# If the react native debugger is off, moment returns an invalid date

Tags: react-native, momentjs

In my RN application, I have the following code.

```
const birthDate = moment(new Date(val));
```

If the RN debugger is off it returns an invalid date error. But if the RN debugger is on, it returns the correct date.

What is the issue here?

Comment: I answered your question below. I would appreciate an upvote and marking it as accepted answer or any other feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was already discussed [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15819). The problem originates from different JavaScript Runtime Environments and the fact that the new date constructor is quite picky. You can overcome that issue by using moment directly to create new dates or write a small function as https://github.com/SahRckr in the github issue proposed:

```
// SahRckr's proposal 
const jsCoreDateCreator = (dateString) => { 
  // dateString *HAS* to be in this format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"  
  let dateParam = dateString.split(/[\s-:]/)  
  dateParam[1] = (parseInt(dateParam[1], 10) - 1).toString()  
  return new Date(...dateParam)  
}
```

Comment: This should work. But I used moment to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please help me solve this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967235/react-native-moment-not-working-for-specific-time-value-without-debug-mode